# How to deal with max{x1, x2} term in the constraint during an optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, economics

I'm working on a producer theory problem in economics where I'm trying to maximize a firm's profit involving two outputs ($q_1$ and $q_2$ with prices $p_1$ and $p_2$ respectively) and two inputs ($z_2$ and $z_2$ with prices $w_1$ and $w_2$ respectively). My constraint is something called a transformation function.

My main objective is to find $q_1^*$ and $q_2^*$ that maximize the profit (following):
$$p_1q_1+p_2q_2-w_1z_1-w_2z_2$$ subject to $$Max(x_1^\gamma,x_2^\gamma) - z_1^\alpha z_2^\beta \leq 0$$

I want to take the first-order condition by taking derivative with respect to $q_1$ and then with $q_2$ but I have no idea how to deal with the $Max$ {$x_1^\gamma,x_2^\gamma $} expression.

Comment: replace the constraint with two linear constraints

Comment: Hi @LinAlg, do you mean something like ($x_1^γ - z_1^α z_2^β \leq 0 $) as first constraint and ($x_2^γ - z_1^α z_2^β \leq 0 $) as second constraint, therefore constraining both the terms inside the maximum function to be less than or equal to the term, $z_1^α z_2^β$?

Comment: yes [and some padding for the minimum length of a comment]